# How do I write the escape char '\' to code

Tags: c#, escaping

How to escape the character `\` in C#?

Comment: For future reference, when searching in Google, the magic words for this sorta thing are "escape" or "escaping" :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You just need to escape it:

```
char c = '\\';
```

Or you could use the Unicode escape sequence:

```
char c = '\u005c';
```

See my [article on strings](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx) for all the various escape sequences available in string/character literals.

Answer (score 13):

You can escape a backslash using a backslash.

```
//String
string backslash = "\\";

//Character
char backslash = '\\';
```

or

You can use the string literal.

```
string backslash = @"\";
char backslash = @"\"[0];
```

Comment: He didn't say he wanted it as a char, he said he wanted to know how to write it.

Comment: @Romoku: Well, the question talks about char rather than string, *and* uses single quotes in the example. I agree it could be clearer though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well I edited in the char to provide a complete answer.

Comment: @Romoku: You might want to get rid of the `@'\'` bit as it's invalid. I had a brain-fart when I included it. Also, the `@` makes it a *verbatim* string literal, as opposed to a *plain* string literal without - both are string literals.

Comment: @JonSkeet I figured `@"\"[0]` was close enough. Probably not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

use double backlash like so "\"

```
"\\"
```

cause an escape

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output it in a string, you can write `"\\"` or as a character, you can write `'\\'`.

Answer (score 1):

Double escape it. Escape escape = no escape! `\\`

Answer (score 1):

Escape it: `"\\"`

or use the verbatim syntax: `@"\"`

Comment: The `@` is for verbatim, not global escape. Verbatim strings contain even the newline characters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To insert a backslash, you need to type it twice:

```
string myPath = "C:\\Users\\YourUser\\Desktop\\YourFile.txt";
```

The string `myPath` should now contain: `C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\YourFile.txt`