# Ignore inline commands like \n in a string

Tags: c#, string

I tried to find how to ignore escape characters like \n in a string
(example string: Console.WriteLine("how\n     are you\n");)
I found how to ignore case sensitive mostly, but those are not escape characters like \n.
(On phone I don't have an example of the whole code. Will update when I can reach laptop)

So, how do I ignore if disable escape characters in C#?

(EDIT)
Thanks for the help, wasn't aware they were called escape commands.
Yes I wanted to show them as characters, sorry for the vague question.

Comment: `\n` is not an inline command, its an [escape character](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/).  Are you trying to strip out all _escape characters_?

Comment: These aren't inline commands. They are escape sequences that represent *characters* like newlines, tabs, double quotes etc. It's not clear what you want to do either. Do you want to replace some of those *characters*? Or type a string literal where `\n ` is interpreted as two characters instead of a single newline?

Comment: Do you need to remove any other characters than `\n`,`\r`,`\r\n`? If no, then just do `var bar = foo.Replace(@"\n", "").Replace(@"\r", "")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748040/how-do-i-write-the-escape-char-to-code

Answer (score 4):

This could be a solution:

```
string a = "how\n are you\n"
a = a.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Idea is always the same, you have to replace such a constractions like `\n`, `\r` etc with empty string. 
More advanced ways of how to do that you could find here: [How to remove new line characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140723/how-to-remove-new-line-characters-from-a-string) or here: [Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp).

On demand of [Yollo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7517846/yollo) here is a one line version:

```
 Console.WriteLine("how\n are you\n".Replace("\n", string.Empty));
```