# How can i split a string by '\'?

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, split

I used a method that granted me a file path and I want to get only the file name.
so I try to use `string.split('\').`
however, it seems like the computer waits for some another closing and does not let me contain this char as a separator.
it expects either ',' or ';' depends on the content.
quick fixing it with constant doesn't solve it as the problem moves recursively to the constant.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/95oon2i40mohb3k/split%20by%20slash.PNG?dl=0

any workaround?

edit:
thanks for all the helpers, '\\' did do the trick :)

Comment: A backslash is often used to "escape" the next character. To get an actual, single, backslash, use `'\\'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file name from a path string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/get-file-name-from-a-path-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Path Class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.8

```
string path1 = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(path1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with two backslashes instead of one to double escape it.

```
path.Split('\\');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash character.

```
string.Split('\\');
```

You can find some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748040/how-do-i-write-the-escape-char-to-code)

Answer (score 2):

```
path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```