# How can I substract the last element of a path in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to obtain in a new string the last element of a path. For ex, for the path

> "C:\Users\MEDIACENTER\Desktop\Resurse_C#\Resurse\Imagini\Cluj1.txt"

I want to obtain "Cluj1.txt".
Because I need a general method because I am working with a DataBase.
The character '\' is the one that I have trouble with, because the C# syntax will not let me use it on the 3rd line of code:

```
01.    while (dr.Read()) // in dr[0] contains the jpg path
02.    {
02.           string v = dr[0].ToString();
03.           char c = '\'; 
04.           string[] s = v.Split(c);            
05.    }
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `string filename = Path.GetFilename(dr[0]);`

Comment: Note that `Path.GetFilename` can also be used to get the name of the last folder in a path that references a folder. Basically, `Path.GetFilename` does exactly what you're looking for, it is not limited to files, it will use the position of the last path separator and return everything after it.

Comment: the '\' character is the escape character - if you want to specify the backslash character you need to use '\\'.  For more info see [How do I write the escape character to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748040/how-do-i-write-the-escape-char-to-code)

Comment: Thank you a lot for all of the information, the escape character made me a lot of problems and now I finally understood it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `Path.GetFileName`

```
var filename = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Users\MEDIACENTER\Desktop\Resurse_C#\Resurse\Imagini\Cluj1.txt");
```